# Node.js - sqlstring alternative which allows named named replacements

Tags: sql, node.js, templates, npm

The `sqlstring` node module allows creating of queries using an ordered array. So if I have a template query like:

```
sqlstring.format('Select * from users where id = ?', ['my_id'])
```

It will become:

```
Select * from users where id = 'my_id'
```

However here I need to remember the order of the question marks, so if the same thing is being in multiple places it becomes a hassle. Is there an alternative which allows me to do the following:

```
sqlstring.format('Select :id + :foo as bar from users where id = :id', {id: 1, foo: 3})
```

Which would become:

```
Select 1 + 3 as bar from users where id = 1
```

I know `knex` query builder does this, but I don't want install the entirety of knex just for the query builder.

Comment: [Squel](https://hiddentao.com/squel/) has a fluent approach. Maybe it can be a more readible alternative for your named params.

Comment: If you can handle input sanitization (or don't care about it), you could also consider [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mysql2` package, that support that format:

[Named placeholders](https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2/blob/master/documentation/Extras.md#named-placeholders)

> You can use named placeholders for parameters by setting
> namedPlaceholders config value or query/execute time option. Named
> placeholders are converted to unnamed ? on the client (mysql protocol
> does not support named parameters). If you reference parameter
> multiple times under the same name it is sent to server multiple
> times.

```
connection.config.namedPlaceholders = true;
connection.execute('select :x + :y as z', {x: 1, y: 2}, function (err, rows) {
     // statement prepared as "select ? + ? as z" and executed with [1,2] values
     // rows returned: [ { z: 3 } ]
 });

connection.execute('select :x + :x as z', {x: 1}, function (err, rows) {
     // select ? + ? as z, execute with [1, 1]
});

connection.query('select :x + :x as z', {x: 1}, function (err, rows) {
     // query select 1 + 1 as z
});
```